# Leaflet framework to show text on MouseOver event

Tags: leaflet

I am using leaflet framework for adding markers to map and showing them on map I want to show some text after hovering over markers. I have written code to add all markers to an array and later on get all markers in `getallMarkers` function to display text on mouseover event of the marker.  It works for

```
({
    "echo" : function(cmp,event,helper) {
        var action = cmp.get("c.getLatLang");

        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            alert("From server: >>" + response.getReturnValue());
            var strLatLng = response.getReturnValue();
            var pos = strLatLng.indexOf(';');
                if (pos == 0)
                {
                    alert('Inside POS is zero');
                    strLatLng = strLatLng.substring(1,strLatLng.length);
                    alert('AFTER cut latlang is>>' + strLatLng + '<<<');
                }
                //alert('String value is>>'+ strLatLng + '<<');
            var firstPairPos = strLatLng.indexOf(';');
            var firstPair = strLatLng.substring(0,firstPairPos);
            var value1 = firstPair.split('#');
            var allpairs = strLatLng.split(';');
            alert('ALLPAIRS array contains>>>' + allpairs + '<<');
                //alert("FIrst PAir is:>>" + value1[0] + '<<' + "value2 is>>" + value1[1]);
                var map;
                var arrMarkers=[];
                var lat = value1[1];
                var lang = value1[2];
                alert ("after first pair:: >>" + lat + ">>" + lang + "<<");
                var map = new L.Map('map');
                //map = L.map('map').setView([lat, lang], 6);
                map.setView([lat,lang], 6);

                L.tileLayer('https://api.tomtom.com/map/1/tile/basic/main/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key={apiKey}', {
                apiKey: 'trv87gvquv8yyfr4nrwgsdzc',
                maxZoom: 18}).addTo(map);


                for (i=0;i<allpairs.length;i++)
                {
                    var j=0,k=0;
                    var newpair = allpairs[i].split('#');
                    var text = newpair[0];
                    var lat1 = newpair[1];
                    var lng1 = newpair[2];
                    alert('lat1 lang1 is allpairs loop>>'+ lat1 + '<<'+ lng1 + '<< text is>>' + text);
                    var title = text;

                     var marker = L.marker([lat1, lng1],'showtext');
                     //marker.on('mouseover',getallmarkers);
                     marker.addTo(map).bindPopup(title);
                     marker.on('mouseover',getallmarkers);
                   // arrMarkers.push(marker);

                    //map.addlayer(popup);
                    //L.marker([lat1, lng1]).addTo(map).bindPopup(title);
                    //L.marker([lat1, lng1],"this is marker title").addTo(map).bindPopup(title);

                }
            function getallmarkers()
            {
            for (l=0;arrMarkers.length>0;l++)
            {
               alert('Inside arrmarkers');
               //var markernew = arrMarkers[l];
               alert('arr markers is >>' + arrMarkers[l] + '<<');
               arrMarkers[l].on('mouseover', function(e){arrMarkers[l].openPopup();});
            }
            }
              //map.on('click', onMapClick);

            }
            else if (state === "ERROR") {

                var errors = response.getError();
                if (errors) {
                    if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                        console.log("Error message: " +
                                 errors[0].message);
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log("Unknown error");
                }
            }
        });

        function onMapClick(e)
        {
                    alert("You clicked the map at ABTEST>>" + e.latlng);
                    var out = e.latlng;
                    alert("Lat Lang on out is>>" + out + "<<");
                    var lat = 51.11732;
                    var lang = 6.78955;

                    var action = cmp.get("c.getNearestVehicles");
                    alert('after getnearestvehicles call');
                    //action.setParams({"strlat":"51117320","strlang":"6789550"});
                    //alert('after setparams call');
            //

                    action.setCallback(this, function(a){
                        alert('INSIDE SETCALLBACK ACTION MAP CLICK');
                        var strLatLang1 = a.getReturnValue();
                       alert("STR LAT LANG1 is>>>" + strLatLang1 + '<<<');

                    });
                    if(callback)
                    {
                    action.setCallback(this, callback)
                    }
            //$A.enqueueAction(action);
                   //helper.callserver();
        }
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Comment: I am adding all markers to an array of markers and i want to invoke openPopup on mouseover event for all markers. pop up is not opening on map

Answer (score 1):

Well, the plugin which I think you are looking for is [Leaflet.Label](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.label).  It is a mature plugin with unobtrusive labels which has been developed for years.  Labels are binded very easily with code such as this

```
L.marker([-37.7772, 175.2606]).bindLabel('Look revealing label!').addTo(map);
```

Demo site is at http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.label/

Leaflet popups are a bit bigger and take up more room on the map, but theoretically they could be used with some code like

```
myFeatureGroup.on('mouseover',function(ev) {
  ev.layer.openPopup()
})
```

Comment: popup opens for 1 marker. But when i put all markers in an array and try to open popup for all markers it doesnt work.

Comment: Leaflet popups only open one at a time. If you want labels appearing for many markers at a time...Leaflet.Label is the way to go.

Comment: I want to open one pop up at a time but what i am saying is popup is shown for 1 marker only. it is not shown for other markers. i am adding all markers to an array inside for loop and on  mouseover event try to invoke function getallmarkers